# Share this App for an Android App

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to add a "Share this app" menu item to my Android App. I know how to create an Intent and share texts etc. But I want to know what content type should be set to while I share an app.

And will the content be like `http://play.google.com/apps/org.example.appname` or will it be something else.

While I tried a search on Google, I ended up with "MyAppSharer" and other similar links.

Comment: Are you asking about using the Share functionality included in the ActionBar (so you will have the standard share control in your AB)?  Or are you asking how to have an action, that when pressed with link to the Play Store (for a particular app)?

Comment: Its "how to have an action, that when pressed with link to the Play Store (for a particular app)"

Comment: OK, current answer is correct then.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just found the link from the Android Developer site today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have been able to understand is that you have to throw an `Intent` with the content as `http://play.google.com/apps/org.example.appname` or your app's Google Play URL.

The intent action should be `Intent.ACTION_SEND` and type should be specified as `"text/plain"`.

[This article](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app) at Android developer site says to use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.android"));
startActivity(intent);
```

If you think there is a better way, do feel free to add as an answer.